# Webpack - app is blank on IE 11: SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I'm using Webpack with my Vuejs app.

I can't get my app to load on IE 11. This is what the console looks like:

[image]

The console states `SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier`

**webpack.config.js**

```
            {
                test: /\.(es6|js|mjs)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                }
            },
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "useBuiltIns": "usage",
                "corejs": 3,
                "modules": false,
                "debug": true
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

**.browerslistrc**

```
> 0.25%
not ie <= 10
```

**main.js**

```
import "core-js/stable";
```

Comment: first thing to confirm is that IE11 is actually running in IE11 mode!! Check under "emulation" tab. Seriously, so many times I've seen it run in some lower version compatibility mode by default (especially "local" pages)

Comment: Okay, just checked, and compatibility mode does not seem to be on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the stacktrace, the error is thrown by the "async" library you’re using. Having a look at the docs (https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/), it says:

> Async should work in any ES2015 environment (Node 6+ and all modern browsers).
> If you want to use Async in an older environment, (e.g. Node 4, IE11) you will have to transpile.

Because `async` cromes from `node_modules` and your Webpack loader config explicitely exclude it, `async` is not transpiled. To make it so, you can change your `exclude` rule like this:

```
exclude: /node_modules\/(?!async)/,
```

But this might not fix the overall IE11 compatibility if you have other incompatible libraries. You can adapt the rule to add as many packages as you need to be transpiled like this:

```
exclude: /node_modules\/(?!async|library2|library3)/,
```